# Is limiting the performance or setting quotas on an Application domain possible?

Tags: c#, performance, appdomain

I know I can view certain counters such as memory usage but can I impose limits on individual app domains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to work on a system where we were attempting to do something similar.

With the regular .NET CLR you only get very crude controls.  You can find out how much memory the AppDomain is using, but it doesn't tend to be up to date, and as memory pressure increases - becomes completely unreliable.

There may be a way, however, to do this if you're willing to go to the level of hosting the CLR through C++, and using the [CLR Hosting APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx#S2).

I've been told it's possible to do things such as intercept memory allocation requests from the hosted CLR. You may also be able to limit I/O requests and CPU utilisation too.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no built-in mechanisms to limit any resource usage on AppDomain level (or even at process level) by .Net application. It includes memory usage, network usage, CPU usage.

You can have permissions restrictions (Code access security) on .Net level for AppDomains, but amount of control essentially stops there.

The only built in mechanism is to restrict CPU usage by cores for whole process. The rest is for application to take care of.